# PostgreSQL: CAST function

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting

I have a problem with a CAST function in PostgreSQL. In particular, I have to convert an arithmetic operation (a percentage calcul), where the operands are int type, in a bigint type. But when I type this command:

```
CAST(("Language".percentage * "Population".population) AS bigint) /100.0 AS pop_speak_lang
```

The outcome is:

> ERROR: integer out of limits

If someone could help me I would really appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need cast

```
"Language".percentage / 100.0 * "Population".population AS pop_speak_lang
```